# How to Increase a timer AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, timer

Hey everyone cant really figure out the easiest approach to this problem.

Basically I have a timer that starts in the beginning of the game like so:

```
//Create new timer object
        tEggTimer = new Timer (nTimerSpeed);
        //Listen for timer intervals
        tEggTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, addEggs, false, 0, true);
        //start timer
        tEggTimer.start();
```

The nTimerSpeed is equal to (800);

Then I add the eggs like so:

```
private function addEggs(e:TimerEvent):void 
    {
        //var eggGlobalPosition:Point = _Egg.localToGlobal(new Point(_Bunny.x, _Bunny.y));

        _Egg = new mcEgg();
        stage.addChild(_Egg);
        _Egg.x = _Bunny.x;
        _Egg.y = _Bunny.y + 30;
        aEggArray.push(_Egg);
        trace(aEggArray.length);

    }
```

So in another enter frame function I want to change the value of the timer to (500), but whenever I try like so:

tEggTimer = new Timer (500);

tEggTimer.start();

like So:

```
private function updateDifficulty():void 
    {
        if (difficultyUpdate) return;

        if (nScore >= 2)
        { 
            tEggTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, addEggs);
            tEggTimer.stop();
            tEggTimer = new Timer(200);
            tEggTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, addEggs);
            tEggTimer.start();
```

But this doesnt do anything but stop the timer entirely.

What can I do in order to decrease the timer correctly?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to change the timer speed, while keeping everything else the same, you could just change the delay property in the timer object.

Sample here:

```
import flash.utils.getTimer;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var speeds:Vector.<int> = new <int>[1000, 2000, 5000];
var currentSpeed:int = 0;

var timer:Timer = new Timer(speeds[currentSpeed]);
function timerTick(inputEvent:TimerEvent):void {
    trace("Timer ticking: "+ getTimer());
}
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerTick, false, 0, true);
timer.start();


function clickedStage(inputEvent:MouseEvent):void {
    currentSpeed = ++currentSpeed % speeds.length;
    timer.delay = speeds[currentSpeed];
    trace("Timer delay set to "+ timer.delay);
}
this.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickedStage, false, 0, true);
```

Clicking on the stage will change the timer delay from 1 second, 2 seconds, 5 seconds and cycle. I'm just using getTimer() to show the rate of which the timer is ticking.

Note that it seems from the output, every time the value is changed, the timer will automatically restart.

Comment: I get these errors: Implicit coercion of a value of type flash.utils:Timer to an unrelated type Class.

Comment: Does it say which line it is at? Try putting it in to a blank new fla (I'm assuming you're using the flash ide).

Comment: Hmm it seems to work just fine in a new fla. Maybe Im doing something wrong ill try again

Comment: hrm, I don't know? =b Out of my example though, it's really just setting timer.delay (or tEggTimer.delay in your code) that is the key part.

Comment: So I gave it ago and there are now no errors. But It doesnt seem to function correctly. Would I be able to do this. Since I want the timer to tick faster<int>[1000, 800, 500]; ? I want it to start off at 1000 then reduce to 800 whenever it is activated in the If statement as shown in my example

Comment: Sure, that is doable. Create the timer with 1000 delay, then set it to 800 within your if statement. What's s the behaviour you're seeing?

Comment: Wait how would I go about creating it with a delay? tEggTimer.delay = 1000; in my constructor?

Comment: You've done so before already: new Timer(1000) - The constructor takes that value and sticks it in the delay property for you upon creation.

Comment: When I add the tEggTimer.delay = 800; in my If statment it just stops. No more eggs come out.

Comment: Why is this so difficult !!!! Aghh!! haha. Sorry man Just cant get this to work at all. I had to create a new timer for the eggs and remove the old timer in the if statement but then i get some funky stuff going on there as well. Once I get the delay to work I know everything will be fine but just cant seem to do it

Comment: Wait i think i finally figured it out OMG. Ill post back soon

Answer (score 1):

```
timer.reset();
timer.delay = 2000;
timer.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

May no be the best way but, instead using nTimerSpeed, make it run through every millisecond:

```
tEggTimer = new Timer (1);
```

Then in your AddEggs function use nTimerSpeed and a counter variable. counter is initialize to 0. Incase all your logic in an if statement, increment counter every time through function. if counter equals nTimerSpeed, allow for them inside the if statement and reset counter.

```
function AddEggs()
{
   if(counter == nTimerSpeed)
   {
       //adding eggs logic
       counter = 0;
   }
   counter++;
}
```

Comment: Hmm interesting not entirely sure on how to implement this though. Ill try and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Did you try saying: `tEggTimer.stop()` just before re-instantiating with the 500 ms version? I'm guessing that your first Timer instance will just keep firing as your new one starts, unless you deliberately stop it.

Comment: No I didnt. What i tried doing at one point was:  tEggTimer = new Timer (500);  tEggTimer.reset(); tEggTimer.start();

Comment: Please try my suggestion & let me know how it goes.

Comment: Yeah I tried but I get nothing Ima update my post maybe it will help with more details.